# Removing a number of consecutive rows that fulfills a certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe, row, vectorization

I am trying to remove consecutive rows in a dataframe if all the values in the rows are less than 1 and it exceeds e.g 4 rows.

Lets say we have a column `[0.1, 0, 5, 4, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 10]`. Then I would like to remove only the middle part `[0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0]` and have left `[0.1, 0, 5, 4, 4, 9, 10]`. The thing is I can easily do this by using a for loop, however I am dealing with over 3 million data points and it takes way too long. Therefore I am looking for a solution that makes use of vectorization in R. Does anyone know what function I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform a convolution/correlation over your dataset. If all elements in 4 consecutive rows are less than 1, then their sum is less than `4 * m`, with `m` being the number of columns of your dataset. Then, it is a matter of upsampling the result correctly. Here is a complete example, with NumPy array (that you can easily extract from your `DataFrame` with `df.to_numpy()`):

```
import numpy as np
"""
Notation: row whose elements are all < 1, will be called "target row"
Task: Remove every target row in a cluster of 4 consecutive target rows

Input: 11 x 5 dataset with target rows [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
Output: pruned dataset with rows [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
(Note that target row 7 must be kept because it's separated from the others)
"""

# Input
n, m = 11, 5
ar = np.random.rand(n, m)
ar[[5, 6, 8, 9, 10]] += 1.
min_rows = 4

# Find all target rows
sums = (ar.sum(axis=1) < ar.shape[1]).astype(np.float32)
print(f"    Sums: {sums}")

# Find centers of clusters with 4 consecutive target rows
kernel = np.ones((min_rows,))
output = np.correlate(sums, kernel, mode="same")
print(f"  Output: {output}")

mask = output == min_rows
print(f"    Mask: {mask.astype(np.float32)}")


# Find all elements in the clusters
mask_ids = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
center = min_rows // 2
rng = np.arange(-center, center + (min_rows % 2 != 0), dtype=np.int32)


ids = (rng + mask_ids.reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
mask[ids] = True
print(f"New Mask: {mask.astype(np.float32)}")

# mask the dataset
ar = ar[~mask]
```